# Why does tensorflow give me completely different results while training when I don't change the file at all?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN with a spatial transformer for the CIFAR-10 dataset and for some reason when i run it for the first time it gets perfectly good results. Then when I run it again it refuses to train, with training accuracy hovering around 10%. However when I move the file into a different folder, it gets good results again... I am so confused.

I have a tf.reset_default_graph() before any tf variables are defined. What could this be?

Loading the data:

```
cifar10_dataset_folder_path = 'cifar-10-batches-py'

class DownloadProgress(tqdm):
    last_block = 0
    def hook(self, block_num=1, block_size=1, total_size=None):
        self.total = total_size
        self.update((block_num - self.last_block) * block_size)
        self.last_block = block_num


if not isfile('cifar-10-python.tar.gz'):
    with DownloadProgress(unit='B', unit_scale=True, miniters=1, desc='CIFAR-10 Dataset') as pbar:
        urlretrieve(
            'https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz',
            'cifar-10-python.tar.gz',
            pbar.hook)

if not isdir(cifar10_dataset_folder_path):
    with tarfile.open('cifar-10-python.tar.gz') as tar:
        tar.extractall()
        tar.close()



def load_label_names():
    return ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']


def load_cfar10_batch(cifar10_dataset_folder_path, batch_id):
    with open(cifar10_dataset_folder_path + '/data_batch_' + str(batch_id), mode='rb') as file:
        # note the encoding type is 'latin1'
        batch = pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')

    features = batch['data'].reshape((len(batch['data']), 3, 32, 32)).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)
    labels = batch['labels']

    return features, labels
```

Processing the data:

```
def normalize(x):
    """
        argument
            - x: input image data in numpy array [32, 32, 3]
        return
            - normalized x 
    """
    min_val = np.min(x)
    max_val = np.max(x)
    x = (x-min_val) / (max_val-min_val)
    return x


#One-hot encode

def one_hot_encode(x):
    """
        argument
            - x: a list of labels
        return
            - one hot encoding matrix (number of labels, number of class)
    """
    encoded = np.zeros((len(x), 10))

    for idx, val in enumerate(x):
        encoded[idx][val] = 1

    return encoded


def _preprocess_and_save(normalize, one_hot_encode, features, labels, filename):
    features = normalize(features)
    labels = one_hot_encode(labels)

    pickle.dump((features, labels), open(filename, 'wb'))

def preprocess_and_save_data(cifar10_dataset_folder_path, normalize, one_hot_encode):
    n_batches = 5
    valid_features = []
    valid_labels = []

    for batch_i in range(1, n_batches + 1):
        features, labels = load_cfar10_batch(cifar10_dataset_folder_path, batch_i)

        # find index to be the point as validation data in the whole dataset of the batch (10%)
        index_of_validation = int(len(features) * 0.1)

        # preprocess the 90% of the whole dataset of the batch
        # - normalize the features
        # - one_hot_encode the lables
        # - save in a new file named, "preprocess_batch_" + batch_number
        # - each file for each batch
        _preprocess_and_save(normalize, one_hot_encode,
                             features[:-index_of_validation], labels[:-index_of_validation], 
                             'preprocess_batch_' + str(batch_i) + '.p')

        # unlike the training dataset, validation dataset will be added through all batch dataset
        # - take 10% of the whold dataset of the batch
        # - add them into a list of
        #   - valid_features
        #   - valid_labels
        valid_features.extend(features[-index_of_validation:])
        valid_labels.extend(labels[-index_of_validation:])

    # preprocess the all stacked validation dataset
    _preprocess_and_save(normalize, one_hot_encode,
                         np.array(valid_features), np.array(valid_labels),
                         'preprocess_validation.p')

    # load the test dataset
    with open(cifar10_dataset_folder_path + '/test_batch', mode='rb') as file:
        batch = pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1')

    # preprocess the testing data
    test_features = batch['data'].reshape((len(batch['data']), 3, 32, 32)).transpose(0, 2, 3, 1)
    test_labels = batch['labels']

    # Preprocess and Save all testing data
    _preprocess_and_save(normalize, one_hot_encode,
                         np.array(test_features), np.array(test_labels),
                         'preprocess_training.p')
preprocess_and_save_data(cifar10_dataset_folder_path, normalize, one_hot_encode)


valid_features, valid_labels = pickle.load(open('preprocess_validation.p', mode='rb'))
```

Placeholders:

```
# Remove previous weights, bias, inputs, etc..
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Inputs
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 32, 32, 3), name='input_x')
y =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 10), name='output_y')
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
```

Here is the architecture:

```
def conv_net(x, keep_prob):

# Identity transformation
initial = np.array([[1., 0, 0], [0, 1., 0]])
initial = initial.astype('float32')
initial = initial.flatten()


#x_reshaped = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 32*32*3])

st1_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[5, 5, 3, 100], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
st2_filter =  tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[5, 5, 100, 200], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
b_st1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[100], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01))
b_st2= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[200], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01))


#preprocess pool
st0_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')



#layer 1
st1 = tf.nn.conv2d(st0_pool, st1_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
st1 = tf.nn.bias_add(st1, b_st1)
st1 = tf.nn.relu(st1)
st1_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(st1)

st1_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(st1_bn, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

#layer 2
st2 = tf.nn.conv2d(st1_pool, st2_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
st2 = tf.nn.bias_add(st2, b_st2)
st2 = tf.nn.relu(st2)
st2_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(st2)

st2_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(st2_bn, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')


#flatten
st1_pool_final = tf.nn.max_pool(st1_pool, ksize=[1,4,4,1], strides=[1,4,4,1], padding='SAME')
st2_pool_final = tf.nn.max_pool(st2_pool, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

flat_features = tf.concat([tf.contrib.layers.flatten(st1_pool_final), tf.contrib.layers.flatten(st2_pool_final)], 1)

#fully connected stn layer
st1FC_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[1200,100], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
st2FC_filter =  tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[100,6], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
b_st1FC = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[100], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01))
b_st2FC= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[6], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01))



# Create variables for fully connected layer for the localisation network
W_fc_loc1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[1200,100], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
b_fc_loc1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[100], mean=0.0, stddev=0.01))

#layer 3
st_fc1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(flat_features)
st_fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(st_fc1, W_fc_loc1), b_fc_loc1)
st_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(st_fc1)
st_fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(st_fc1, keep_prob)

#layer 4

W_fc2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 6]), name='sp_weight_fc2')
b_fc2 = tf.Variable(initial_value=initial, name='sp_biases_fc2')

sp_fc2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(st_fc1)
sp_fc2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(sp_fc2, W_fc2), b_fc2)



out_size = (32, 32,3)
h_trans = transformer(x, sp_fc2, out_size)




conv1_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 3, 64], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
conv2_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 64, 128], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
conv3_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[5, 5, 128, 256], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
conv4_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[5, 5, 256, 512], mean=0, stddev=0.08))

# 1, 2
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(h_trans, conv1_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
conv1_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')
conv1_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv1_pool)

# 3, 4
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1_bn, conv2_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
conv2_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')    
conv2_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv2_pool)

# 5, 6
conv3 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv2_bn, conv3_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
conv3 = tf.nn.relu(conv3)
conv3_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv3, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')  
conv3_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv3_pool)

# 7, 8
conv4 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv3_bn, conv4_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
conv4 = tf.nn.relu(conv4)
conv4_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv4, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')
conv4_bn = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv4_pool)

# 9
flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(conv4_bn)  

# 10
full1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=flat, num_outputs=128, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full1 = tf.nn.dropout(full1, keep_prob)
full1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full1)

# 11
full2 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full1, num_outputs=256, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full2 = tf.nn.dropout(full2, keep_prob)
full2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full2)

# 12
full3 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full2, num_outputs=512, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full3 = tf.nn.dropout(full3, keep_prob)
full3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full3)    

# 13
full4 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full3, num_outputs=1024, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
full4 = tf.nn.dropout(full4, keep_prob)
full4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(full4)        

# 14
out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=full3, num_outputs=10, activation_fn=None)
return out, h_trans
```

Hyper-params and optimizers etc:

```
#Hyperparameters
epochs = 10
batch_size = 128
keep_probability = 0.7
learning_rate = 0.001

#Cost Function & optimizer
#### INIT
#with tf.name_scope('logits_and_stn_output'):
logits, h_trans = conv_net(x, keep_prob)

model = tf.identity(logits, name='logits') # Name logits Tensor, so that can be loaded from disk after training

# Loss and Optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=logits, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Accuracy
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
```

Training Loop:

```
print('Training...')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initializing the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        # Loop over all batches
        n_batches = 5
        for batch_i in range(1, n_batches + 1):
            for batch_features, batch_labels in load_preprocess_training_batch(batch_i, batch_size):
                train_neural_network(sess, optimizer, keep_probability, batch_features, batch_labels)



            print('Epoch {:>2}, CIFAR-10 Batch {}:  '.format(epoch + 1, batch_i), end='')
            print_stats(sess, batch_features, batch_labels, cost, accuracy)

    # Save Model
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    save_path = saver.save(sess, save_model_path)
```

Comment: Without your relevant code, it's hard to figure out what could be going on. Can you please update with what your code looks like?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54973022/edit) the question accordingly. Please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and give sample inputs, outputs and the error messages you get, if any. This will help us to determine what is going on and improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: @JordanSinger I have added my code!